# Cortex-M3 kill an interrupt routine from a preemptive routine

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, interrupt, cortex-m

I am using Cortex-M3 processor on STM32F103.
I have one lower priority interrupt running periodically and another higher priority interrupt which runs on particular events.
Both of them acts on the same output.

I need to use preemption for having accurate timing: the higher priority interrupt (HPI) is able to come over the lower priority one (LPI).
When this happens, because the HPI can come at any point of the LPI code, sometimes the routine LPI resume the execution after being interrupted by HPI overwriting improperly the output.

Is it possible to pull out from the stack the LPI, so that it doesn't resume at the end of HPI?

Thanks a lot,

Marco

Comment: Are the two ISRs equivalent? i.e. if the HPI could detect that it's preempted the LPI in order to terminate it, could it not conversely simply skip its own processing and let the LPI continue instead? Or is it that they're otherwise completely unrelated and you're just missing a sufficient mutual exclusion mechanism on your output channel?

Comment: yes, the HPI can detect that it has preempted the LPI, but the LPI cannot all the times detect that it has been preempted by the HPI . Even if I set a flag in the HPI routine and before writing the output in the LPI routine I check that the flag is not set, because the two LPI and HPI are triggered at unrelated frequencies, it will happen that the HPI will be triggered between the flag check and the output set. That why I would like to have an instruction in the HPI that is something like: if LPI routine  is active then kill it.

Comment: This is an XY problem and you do **not** want this. Use a different approach, e.g. accesses or locking during the manipulation routing or atomic operation. Also the STM32F1 supports bit-band region for GPIO and provides hardware-support to set/clear bits on a GPIO with a single write (atomic).

Comment: Thanks Olaf, I will extend the picture of the problem. The LPI is calculating a PWM duty-cycle of a sinusoidal shaped current. The output we were discussing about are the four compare channels of TIM4. PWM is used for controlling sinusoidal currents. To avoid beats, PWM need to be synchronized in phase with sinusoidal frequency (TIM4 CNT resetted and PWM duty-cycle recalculated). Synch interrupt must be at higher priority to avoid vibrations and noisy behaviour.

Comment: I would think about setting "recalc_needed" flags in either interrupt, and actually doing the recalc on a compare or rollover match of the timer.